# R different calculations in dataframe based on row condition

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe df:

```
a<-c("Red","Red","Green","Red")
b<-c(1,1,1,1)
df<-data.frame(a,b)
```

I would like to +1 to b when the row of a is Red and -1 when it is Green. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Try with `ifelse` i.e. `with(df, ifelse(a == 'Red', b + 1, b - 1))` or `with(df, b + (a == "Red") - (a == 'Green'))`

Comment: `b` is character.

Comment: Now it is double. Perfect @akrun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a logical vector itself

```
df$b <- with(df, b + (a == "Red") - (a == 'Green'))
```

-output

```
> df
      a b
1   Red 2
2   Red 2
3 Green 0
4   Red 2
```

---

Or if there are only two unique values in 'a' column, use `ifelse`

```
df$b <- with(df, ifelse(a == 'Red', b + 1, b - 1))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

Comment: In my df (from OPs) input. the b column is character. Maybe we need to transform to numeric?!

Comment: @TarJae I think it is a mistake by OP by calling `cbind`  which created a matrix

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = c("Red","Red","Green","Red"), 
  b = c(1,1,1,1)
)

df %>%  
  mutate(b = case_when(a == "Red" ~ b + 1, 
                       a == "Green" ~ b - 1, 
                       TRUE ~ b))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   a         b
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Red       2
#> 2 Red       2
#> 3 Green     0
#> 4 Red       2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, b := fcase(a == "Red", b + 1,
                    a == "Green", b - 1, rep_len(TRUE, length(b)), b)]
```

**Output**

```
       a b
1:   Red 2
2:   Red 2
3: Green 0
4:   Red 2
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("Red", "Red", "Green", "Red"), b = c(1, 
1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```